# 2D iterator access in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I'm working on a 2D table with std::map() to count how many times one number transitions to another number.  I've run into two problems.  First, my first transition doesn't show (1->2).  Second, all my transitions are showing only one time (2->3 and 3->1 both happen twice).

I can see why the transitions are only happening once.  The iterator doesn't see currentVal and goes to else, where it adds the values then exits.  I'm not sure how to fix this though.  Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//import midi notes
vector <int> midiFile = {1, 2, 3, 1, 20, 5, 2, 3, 1};

//create a 2d hashmap for matrix
map <string, map <string, int> > mCounts;

//strings for the previous value and current value
string prevVal = "";
string currentVal = "";

void addNumbers(vector <int> midiFile) {

    for (int i = 0; i < midiFile.size(); i++) {
        currentVal = to_string(midiFile[i]);

        if(prevVal == "") {
            prevVal = currentVal;   //first value
        } else {
            //playCounts is temporary map to store counts of current val in relation to previous val
            map <string, int> playCounts;

            map <string, int> ::iterator iterator;
            iterator = playCounts.find(currentVal);

            //if mCounts doesn't contain the value yet, create a new hashmap
            if(iterator != playCounts.end()){

                int counter = iterator -> second;
                mCounts[prevVal] [currentVal] = counter + 1;


            } else {
                playCounts.insert(pair <string, int>(currentVal, 1));
                mCounts [prevVal] = playCounts;

            }

            prevVal = currentVal;

        }

        //find values already in map
        map <string, map <string, int> > ::iterator it;
        it = mCounts.find(prevVal);

        if (it != mCounts.end()) {
            //if value is found, do nothing
        } else {
            mCounts.insert(pair <string, map <string, int>>(prevVal, map <string, int>()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do try and avoid making a habit of `using namespace std`. It can lead to a whole lot of confusion later on.

Comment: Do I see it right that you create `playCounts` within the loop, i.e. creating an empty map with each loop iteration?

Comment: BTW: I'd suggest to use a single map (not a "2D" map) and use a transition like `2 .. 3` as a single key like `2->3` and manage the count accordingly.

Comment: Thanks tadman.  Yes Stephan, this is a great point.  I created it thinking that each iteration would have a different value, but maybe I need to make `playCounts` a global variable.

Comment: Ok I've made `playCounts` global and that's fixed most of the transitions, though some of them aren't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with small integers < 128.  Just use a matrix where `transition[i][j]` is the number of transitions from i to j.  Normally I recommend a flat buffer for matrices with index multiplication to access the 2d dimension, or a prewritten class wrapper around the same thing (see [Eigen](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjopvLz6_vSAhXs7oMKHbKvAVoQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Feigen.tuxfamily.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGi0wxMLU4MgkIA4YRyJUH2dkiKCg&sig2=0tqlsyjPgPJW5zYMDbZlFQ)).  But in this case, the matrix is so small, you can just use

```
int transition[128][128];
```

Of course you want to typedef this and pass it by reference. 
Not only will all your operations be easier and more transparent, but using a transition matrix admits analysis that's not possible any other way: eigenvectors for equilibrium states, etc.

For larger problems where the transitions are sparse and you can't afford a dense matrix, use an actual sparse matrix class, which is essentially what you're trying to roll yourself.

```
typedef int transitionMatrix[128][128];

void addNumbers(const vector <int> &midiFile, transitionMatrix &mCounts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < midiFile.size()-1; i++) {
        int prev = midiFile[i];
        int curr = midiFile[i+1];
        mCounts[prev][curr]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works really well.  This was my initial thought on how to approach it, but thought a 128x128 matrix would be a lot to compute.  One more question.  The `mCounts` results print as `midiFile` processes through the for loop, however I want it to only print all results once the for loop has finished.  Any ideas on this?  Concerned that as I calculate my randomization weights that the counts may skew my results. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown any printing code, and my snippet above doesn't print anything.  After calling `addNumbers`, you'll have a finished matrix, which you can print however you want.  You probably want a print method which runs a double-loop over both indices, tests for non-zero, and prints the indices and the count.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach, in which the two integers making up a transition are combined to a single string of the form `"1->2"`, which then serves as key in a count map. The code becomes more concise that way. Further, I eliminated global variables and made them local ones or parameters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using std::vector;
using std::map;
using std::string;

void addNumbers(const vector <int> &midiFile, map <string, int> &mCounts) {

    for (int i = 0; i < midiFile.size()-1; i++) {

        int prev = midiFile[i];
        int curr = midiFile[i+1];
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << prev << "->" << curr;

        mCounts[ss.str()]++;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector <int> midiFile = {1, 2, 3, 1, 20, 5, 2, 3, 1};
    map <string, int> mCounts;

    addNumbers(midiFile, mCounts);
    for (auto const& x : mCounts)
    {
        std::cout << x.first  // transition
        << ':'
        << x.second // count
        << std::endl ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1->2:1
1->20:1
2->3:2
20->5:1
3->1:2
5->2:1
```

Comment: Appreciate this.  My only concern with this approach is that I'm going to use these transitions to define midi notes that are going to be played in real time (a Markov Chain).  So when note 20 plays, I need a way to reference that number into its appropriate transition (20->5), but the values are linked together.  The only way I can see to do this is by adding an outer map, unless you see another way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that doesn't use nested maps and doesn't convert notes to strings (but assumes that notes are nonnegative):

```
// This snippet uses c++11 syntax
#include <map>

// Code in this example assumes that valid notes are nonnegative
struct transition {
    int from;
    int to;
};

// Comparison operator required to make transition usable as a
// key in std::map
bool operator< (const transition& l, const transition& r) {
    return l.from < r.from || (l.from == r.from && l.to < r.to);
}

// Range of all transitions with respective counter
// starting from a particular note 
std::pair<std::map<transition, int>::const_iterator,
    std::map<transition, int>::const_iterator>
transitions_from(int from_note,
        const std::map<transition, int>& transition_counters) {
    return std::make_pair(transition_counters.lower_bound(transition{from_note, -1}),
            transition_counters.upper_bound(transition{from_note + 1, -1}));
}

int counter_for(transition t, const std::map<transition, int>& transition_counters) {
    const auto it = transition_counters.find(t);
    if (it != transition_counters.end()) {
        return it->second;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> notes = {1, 2, 3, 1, 20, 5, 2, 3, 1};
    std::map<transition, int> transition_counters;
    int previous_note = -1;
    for (int note: notes) {
        if (previous_note != -1) {
            transition t{previous_note, note};
            transition_counters[t] += 1;
        }
        previous_note = note;
    }

    std::cout << "all encountered transitions:\n";
    for (const auto& entry: transition_counters) {
        std::cout << '(' << entry.first.from << " -> " << entry.first.to << "): " << entry.second << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "transitions from 1:\n";
    const auto transitions_from_1 = transitions_from(1, transition_counters);
    for (auto it = transitions_from_1.first; it != transitions_from_1.second; ++it) {
        std::cout << '(' << it->first.from << " -> " << it->first.to << "): " << it->second << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "counters for individual transitions:\n";
    std::cout << "(1 -> 2): " << counter_for(transition{1, 2}, transition_counters) << '\n';
    std::cout << "(2 -> 1): " << counter_for(transition{2, 1}, transition_counters) << '\n';
}
```